# Tombstoning not works after executing photo chooser task or camera capture task in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my photo enhancement application, When i am trying to test tombstone functionality it will work without any issue. But when i try for Photo Chooser Task or Camera Capture task, The first time when  i choose Photo from the photo library it works without any issue. But later if i try to test toambstone the app only works in FAS mode. I tried this in both device and emulator but the result was same. Is there any other option i need to enable other than "Toambstone upon deactivation while debugging" in the project properties.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/95110763/ChooseLauncherSample.zip (check the sample for more information)

Comment: I checked on an empty project and have got the same result. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check the answer given by Matt Lacey on a similar question [on StackOverflow here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889335/how-to-take-a-photo-and-email-it)
It gives some insights on how to use the `CameraCaptureTask`with Tombstoning!

Comment: This is not the issue what i am mentioned here. My issue is the application is not tombstoning...Please read the question properly..

Comment: Still could be if you implemented it like Matt's code example, it could be working now. I was only suggesting a possible link between Tombstoning en CaptureTask in general... I do have to say I didn't open your zip to verify, because zips are blocked at my current work station

Comment: Yes, i implemented the one in the same manner.. But still it happens. Think its a known issue for MS.